# How can i get the r_contactinfo from linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api

Hi i have done the basic app which can get the company page details of the user. Now i have to get the email ids of the user who..? liked the page and post of the particular company page, is there any API to get this details. Also how to get the r_contactinfo from the linkedin if i use this in my API call its shows error.

In linkedin they have mentioned tat we have to get permission for this, how to do that.
Even i have tried the below url to get user details. It returns error.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url,industry,positions:(id,title,summary,start-date,end-date,is-current,company:(id,name,type,size,industry,ticker)),educations:(id,school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities,notes)),num-results)?first-name=parameter&last-name=parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the company followers by segment. Refer https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#get_followers

For getting user's who liked a specific update from the company, check https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#get_update_likes

r_contactinfo is only available through "Apply with LinkedIn" partner programs. You cannot access this otherwise. Check partner programs registration and apply for the relevant one based on your application.

https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs